# Houghcircle, Contour & approx polydp. Unable to find heptagon

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

[image: mixed template matching & hough circle; very crude solution]I have been able to detect circular coins and find brightness  & radii values but not a heptagon. I have used hough-circle in open cv to find circle and found brightness & radii to find value of coin in question. Unable to detect heptagon(non-circle) object ie 50 pence. Tried template matching o find heptagon but i need to consolidate both circular & heptagon coins together to find total value of all coins in picture.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def av_pix(img,circles,size):
    av_value = []
    for coords in circles[0,:]:
        col = np.mean(img[coords[1]-size:coords[1]+size,coords[0]-size:coords[0]+size])
        #print(img[coords[1]-size:coords[1]+size,coords[0]-size:coords[0]+size])
        av_value.append(col)
    return av_value   


def get_radius(circles):
    radius = []
    for coords in circles[0,:]:
        radius.append(coords[2])    
    return radius

img = cv2.imread('source.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
original_image = cv2.imread('source.png',1)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5,5), 0)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,0.75,120,param1=50,param2=27,minRadius=90,maxRadius=120)

print(circles)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
count = 1
for i in circles[0,:]:
    
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(original_image,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(original_image,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    #cv2.putText(original_image, str(count),(i[0],i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0,0,0), 2)
    count += 1

radii = get_radius(circles)
print(radii)

bright_values = av_pix(img,circles,20)
print(bright_values)

values = []
for a,b in zip(bright_values,radii):
    if a > 150 and b > 110:
        values.append(10)
    elif a > 150 and b <= 110:
        values.append(5)
    elif a < 150 and b > 110:
        values.append(2)
    elif a < 150 and b < 110:
        values.append(1)        
print(values)           
count_2 = 0
for i in circles[0,:]:
    
    cv2.putText(original_image, str(values[count_2]) + 'p',(i[0],i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0,0,0), 2)
    count_2 += 1
cv2.putText(original_image, 'ESTIMATED TOTAL VALUE: ' + str(sum(values)) + 'p', (200,100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.3, 255)
cv2.imshow('Detected Coins',original_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: circular & heptagon coin- to detect and find total value]

I have tried to find contour and approxpolydp, found this but unable to adapt to a heptagon.

```
import numpy as np 
img = cv2.imread('capstone_coins.png')  #read image from system
cv2.imshow('original', img)    #Displaying original image
cv2.waitKey(0) 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #Convert to grayscale image
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 9, 255)            #Determine edges of objects in an image

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  

(contours,_) = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #Find contours in an image
print(len(contours))
def detectShape(c):          #Function to determine type of polygon on basis of number of sides
       shape = 'unknown' 
       peri=cv2.arcLength(cnt,True) 
       vertices = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.89 * peri, True)
       sides = len(vertices) 
       if (sides == 3): 
            shape='triangle' 
       elif(sides==4): 
             x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
             aspectratio=float(w)/h 
             if (aspectratio==1):
                   shape='square'
             else:
                   shape="rectangle" 
       elif(sides==5):
            shape='pentagon' 
       elif(sides==6):
            shape='hexagon' 
       elif(sides==7): 
            shape='heptagon' 
       elif(sides==10): 
            shape='star'
       else:
           shape='circle' 
       return shape 
for cnt in contours:
    moment=cv2.moments(cnt) 
    cx = int(moment['m10'] / moment['m00']) 
    cy = int(moment['m01'] / moment['m00']) 
    shape=detectShape(cnt) 
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],-1,(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.putText(img,shape,(cx,cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0),2)  #Putting name of polygon along with the shape 
    cv2.imshow('polygons_detected',img) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried template matching and found the heptagon but cannot club the two contours together.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('capstone_coins.png',0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv2.imread('heptagon.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR',
            'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I have found the circular coins & with brightness value & radii calculated value. Need to detect 50 pence heptagon & add that to total value.

Comment: Why Hough? You can just select the background by color, invert to get the coins, then split if necessary with dt+watershed.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I am having problem detecting a round and not round objects together. I have used template matching to find the 50p coin.

Comment: Once you get more sides than 4 or 5, the object becomes very hard to determine that it is not a circle. Up to 4 or 5, you can get the contour and then use approxPolyDP() to limit the number of sides. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: I have added the code i used for contour & approxpolydp(). Unable to find all circles but most importantly not sure if what I did is correct for heptagon @fmw42

Comment: @CrisLuengo how to distinguish circle and heptagon? having difficulty there

Comment: Use approxpolydp() to find polygons, not circles.

Comment: I did, had an issue at line ''cx = int(moment['m10'] / moment['m00']) '' in the above code. i used template matching & Houghcircle to achieve what I want: to detect coins & estimate total value. I will keep on working on the approxpolydp(). Thank you!